# Anything Slider only positioned correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some issues using AnythingSlider that can be found here [Anything Slider link](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) and I have used this before without much trouble. However, today, I am noticing that it is only positioning correctly in Firefox.

IE, Safari, and Chrome, it is positioned below where it needs to be.

My site is here : [Link to site with the problem][2]

UPDATE*** It has something to do with the Ribbon Navigation. I removed it and it was positioned correctly ****

I will post the html code down here:

```
<!-- AnythingSlider Begin -->
    $(window).resize(function(){
 $('#slider').height( $(window).width()/2.3 );
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    theme           : 'metallic',
    autoPlay: true,
        delay: 5000,
        mode: 'fade',
        resizeContents: true,
easing          : 'easeInOutBack',
toggleArrows        : true,
toggleControls      : true, 
navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){
return [ 'Appetizers','Sandwhiches and more','Save room for dessert','Finish up in our giftshop' ] [index - 1];
}, 
onSlideComplete : function(slider){
// alert('Welcome to Slide #' + slider.currentPage);
                }
});//end function
});//end ready
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="containertop">
<div class="center">

<ul id="slider" >
        <li>
        <img src="http://www.barrowwebdesigns.com/templates/deli/images/potatoskins.jpg" title="Lemon Yogurt with Blueberry" alt="Lemon Yogurt with Blueberry"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="http://www.barrowwebdesigns.com/templates/deli/images/subs.jpg" title="Watermelon Lemonade Gelato" alt="Watermelon Lemonade Gelato"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="http://www.barrowwebdesigns.com/templates/deli/images/cake.JPG" title="Making Watermelon Lemonade " alt="Making Watermelon Lemonade"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img src="http://www.barrowwebdesigns.com/templates/deli/images/giftshop.JPG" title="Banana Pudding!"  alt="Banana"/>

        </li>



 </ul>
     </div> <!--end center-->   







    <div class="clear"></div>
<img src="http://www.barrowwebdesigns.com/templates/deli/images/paperbottom.jpg" alt="this isn't working" width="900px"  />
</div><!--end containertop -->
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been staring at this awhile now.
[image: Screen in Firefox]

[image: Screen in IE, Chrome, Safari]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remving `overflow: hidden` from here (theme-metallic.css line 237):

```
.anythingSlider .anythingWindow {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: wich avoid it to see empty  r-triangle-top & r-triangle-bottom, flotting in its area (good to know what's happening there float+overflow) just remove position relative on those two to see where they really are (pieces of ribbon)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it comes from **r-triangle-top** & **r-triangle-bottom**, wich are in the way pushing down your slider.

Try set them in absolute position or give them a negative margin-bottom **no to stand in the way**(area where you expect slider to set) .

Position:relative , moves things at screen only, but they keep their position in the flow of your document.(like does transform or some activex in IE)